# Xcode - Error occurs when compiling app in 64-bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, types, 64-bit

I am working with Xcode and have changed my app to compile in 32 and 64-bit, this has caused errors to occur.

I am getting the error:
"Multiple methods named "count" found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes"

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.sections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[self.sections objectAtIndex: section]  count];
}
```

I believe this is caused by the 64-bit version no longer viewing them as the same type.

The error occurs inside the second function. Is this a matter of simply type casting? If so what should I be casting 'count' to?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Split the line into two. Assign the object from the array to a variable with the proper object type. Then get the count off that object.

Comment: @rmaddy what would the proper object type be?

Comment: The type matching the objects that you put in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know which method this object responds to. You send a "count" message. The compiler goes through all the count methods of all classes that it knows about. If there are more than two different ones, it has to complain.

You could write

```
NSArray *tempArray=[self.sections objectAtIndex: section];
return [tempArray  count];
```